# SQL Query - select where things are different

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a little help with a SQL query (SQL Server 2012).

I have written a script which calculates the SHA256 of a set of files stored across a number of servers and stores it in a database table with columns:

- Server
- FileName
- FileHash

Some example rows from the table:

```
SRVDB001, Address.xsd, CF4658A...F674
SRVDB002, Address.xsd, CF4658A...F674
SRVDB001, Company.xsd, BE6E5C3...76E3
```

I would like to write a SQL query which returns a list of files where the hash is not the same across all servers - i.e. one of the files is different on one of the servers.

The only thing I can think of is a `OUTER JOIN` against a subquery `(SELECT DISTINCT [FileName]...)` but I don't really know where to start.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have the query you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @FilesOnServers TABLE
(
    [ServerName] varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    [FileName] nvarchar(256) NOT NULL,
    [FileHash] varbinary(512) NOT NULL  
)

INSERT INTO @FilesOnServers(ServerName, [FileName], [FileHash])
VALUES
('SRVDB001', 'Address.xsd', 0xCF4658AF674),
('SRVDB002', 'Address.xsd', 0xCF4658AF675),
('SRVDB001', 'Company.xsd', 0xBE6E5C376E3);


SELECT DISTINCT F.FileName
FROM
    @FilesOnServers F
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM 
            @FilesOnServers F2
        WHERE
            F.[FileName] = F2.[FileName]
            AND F.FileHash <> F2.FileHash
            AND F.ServerName <> F2.ServerName
    )
```

Comment: It's easy to answer questions like yours. Precise and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
select file_name from your_table
group by file_name, file_hash
having count(*) > 1
```

It groups by file_name and file_hash and only returns names where there is more than one record in the result.  So if the same file_name and file_hash appeared in all records, that would produce a single resultant row and therefore be filtered out by the HAVING clause.

Comment: Thanks for the super-quick response Carl

Answer (score 0):

It looks for distinct FileHashes for each FileName. If more then 1 distinct FileHash is found for a FileName it returns the FileName.

```
SELECT FileName
FROM Table
GROUP BY FileName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT FileHash) > 1
```